# No overloads for "update" match the provided arguments

Tags: python, fastapi, python-typing, pyright

I'm currently reading FastAPI's tutorial user guide and pylance is throwing the following warning:

> No overloads for "update" match the provided argumentsPylancereportCallIssue
> typing.pyi(690, 9): Overload 2 is the closest match

[Here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameters-and-string-validations) is the code that is throwing the warning:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(q: str | None = None):
    results = {"items": [{"item_id": "Foo"}, {"item_id": "Bar"}]}
    if q:
        results.update({"q": q}) # warning here
    return results
```

I tried changing `Python › Analysis: Type Checking Mode` to `basic` and using the Pre-Release version of Pylance but warning persists.

Comment: Since you copied the code straight from the documentation, I suspect this is an issue with the type hints in FastAPI.

Comment: @Barmar no, this has nothing to do with FastAPI typing - they obviously do not provide `dict.update` type hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're bitten by intelligent type inference. To make it clear, I'll get rid of FastAPI dependency and reproduce on a simpler case:

```py
foo = {"foo": ["bar"]}
foo["bar"] = "baz"
```

Whoops, `mypy` (or `pylance`) error. I don't have Pylance available anywhere nearby, so let's stick with `mypy` - the issue is the same, wording may differ.

> E: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", target has type "list[str]")  [assignment]

Now it should be clear: `foo` is inferred as `dict[str, list[str]]` on first assignment. We can add `reveal_type` to confirm, here's [the playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=9aff5f21d5766cdf8c4581f77a013927). Now type checker rightfully complains: you're trying to set a `str` as a value in dict with value type of `list[str]`. Bad idea.

So, what now? You need to tell typechecker that you don't want inference to be this precise. You have few options (any of the following will work):

```py
from typing import Any, TypedDict, NotRequired

class Possible(TypedDict):
    foo: list[str]
    bar: NotRequired[str]

foo: dict[str, Any] = {"foo": ["bar"]}
foo: dict[str, object] = {"foo": ["bar"]}
foo: dict[str, list[str] | str] = {"foo": ["bar"]}
foo: Possible = {"foo": ["bar"]}
```

What's the difference?

- `object` is a "just something" type - such type that you know almost nothing about it. You can't add or multiply objects or pass them to functions requiring some specific types, but can e.g. print it. I'd argue that this solution is best for your use case, because you don't do anything with the dict afterwards.
- `Possible` `TypedDict` is a runner-up here: if this dict defines some important structure that you heavily use in processing later, you'd better say explicitly what each key means.
- `Any` means "leave me alone, I know what I'm doing". It'd probably be a good solution if you use this dict somehow later - `object` will require a lot of type narrowing to work with, and `Any` will just work.
- Union solution is the worst, unless your keys are really dynamic (no semantic meaning). Type checker will shout at you whenever you try to use a value as either of union types - it can always be of another type. (this is not a general advice: `dict[str, int | str]` may be a great type for something where keys do not represent a structure like JS object)

So, in your specific case

```py
@app.get("/items/")
async def read_items(q: str | None = None):
    results: dict[str, object] = {"items": [{"item_id": "Foo"}, {"item_id": "Bar"}]}
    if q:
        results.update({"q": q}) # warning here
    return results
```

should pass.

Since you and other answerers got mislead by overload, here's how `MutableMapping.update` (`dict` subclasses `MutableMapping` in stubs) looks in [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/bba8cbd6f8e1bd54228955528c342c6e31bb7477/stdlib/typing.pyi#L688):

```py
class MutableMapping(Mapping[_KT, _VT]):
    ...  # More methods
    
    @overload
    def update(self, __m: SupportsKeysAndGetItem[_KT, _VT], **kwargs: _VT) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def update(self, __m: Iterable[tuple[_KT, _VT]], **kwargs: _VT) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def update(self, **kwargs: _VT) -> None: ...
```

I have no idea why "Overload 2 is the closest match", accoding to Pylance, but you should hit the first one, of course.

Comment: For reference, [here](https://pyright-play.net/?code=GYexAIF5wbwIlCOAucBtOAjAhgJzgLoC%2BAsAFC4CmAbpdgDYD6ALgJ4AOlAFIgJTmIMOfASjgs2AF5xyQA)'s how Pyright sees the same piece of code.

Comment: Oh, @InSync thanks! I know that Pylance uses Pyright under the hood, do errors pass through unchanged?

Comment: I just created a new project in VSCode to check, and it seems that Pylance added the "Overload 2 is the closest match" part. Either that, or Pyright could emit such a message, but only for a specific kind of LSP request not used in the online playground.

Comment: Regarding the "Overload 2 is the closest match" part, [it's expected](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/discussions/7292).